# finding data sources for android app

Tags: android

I've come across this problem when thinking about creating different apps for Android. I see these apps that show you the  weather cast or sport results, and I wonder which is the source they get all data from.

I assume they don't have their own database which they fill with data manually and live. I suppose they use some kind of web service, data source or something like that. I don't know if web service is the correct term to use in this case (english is not even my native language).

So I would like to know the correct term for what I'm looking for, plus any guidance on finding this kind of services, in order to be able to develop apps using this kind of data sources.

I think this question will help many programming students like me.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you trying to develope- Some apps use simple GET/POST Requests and get it's data back formatted as JSON or XML (which is the common case).

Some uses SOAP for getting their data.

In some cases they are using plain Sockets or CouchDB.

In some cases they are using Push Mechanism (specially for android) like GCM to send their data to the client.

It always depends what you want to do.